# How to accept user input from within a function?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am new to Python. This code snippet is supposed to define a function getinput(), which is supposed to accept user input and put that value into variable stuff. Then I call the function, and print the value of the variable stuff.

```
def getinput():
  stuff = input("Please enter something.")
getinput()
print(stuff)
```

The problem is that the program is not working as expected and I get the error:

```
NameError: name 'stuff' is not defined
```

In contrast, without defining and calling a function, this code works just fine:

```
stuff = input("Please enter something.")
print(stuff)
```

And I can't figure out why that should be so.

Please help. I am learning Python to coach my kid through his school course, and I am using Google Colab with Python 3.7.11, I believe.

Comment: You are printing outside the function. Move```print(stuff)``` inside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of possibilities of printing `stuff` that you could do -

```
def getinput():
  stuff = input("Please enter something.")
  print(stuff)
getinput()
```

You can print it inside function and call it

---

```
def getinput():
  stuff = input("Please enter something.")
  return stuff
print(getinput())
```

You can return the `stuff` and print it (**BEST Solution**)

---

```
def getinput():
    global stuff
    stuff = input("Please enter something.")

getinput()
print(stuff)
```

Or you could use global keyword

Comment: Ok, +1, but: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: I know, I am just giving all the code that can be used here. I have also told which one is better

Comment: Thank you, I have accepted this answer as it also introduced me to the concept of a global variable - though I am getting the sense it is not a good practice to use it. I will just use return values instead. But good and complete answer.

Comment: The best solution is returning the variable

Comment: Yeah, that's what I had written

Answer (score 4):

Variables defined within a function are local in scope to that function, however, you can return values from functions so you can do what you want like this:

```py
def getinput():
    sth = input("Please enter something.")
    return sth
stuff = getinput()
print(stuff)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, there is a concept of the scope of a variable. You create a stuff variable inside a function and the variable can only be used there. There is no such variable outside the function. You can do this:

```
def getinput():
    getinput.stuff = input('Please enter something')
getinput()
print(getinput.stuff)
```

Or you can return value from function:

```
def getinput():
    stuff = input('Please enter something')
    return stuff
s = getinput()
print(s)
```